# Is it possible to create compile time checked parametrized generic type?

Tags: java, generics

The effect I would like to achieve is depicted by the example below:

```
public <T extends Collection> T<String> mainSolution(T<String> words)
{
    return Collections2.transform(words, w -> w.length() + w.toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: No, Java doesn't have higher-kinded generics like this.  You cannot express this with the Java type system.

Comment: I think you mean `<T extends Collection<?>>`, not the raw type `<T extends Collection>`.

Comment: Does it make any diffrence? Since higher-kinded generics are not supported, the type parameter will get erased.

Comment: Do you mean `public <T extends Collection<String>> mainSolution(T words)`?

Comment: I mean it and it wont work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is that you want to pass a `Collection` (or any subclass) of `String`s to a method which does a transformation and returns the collection after the transformation. The resulting collection is of the same type as the one passed in.

If that is the case you were nearly there, just stumbled on some syntax.

Here is the code:

```java
  public <T extends Collection<String>> T mainSolutions(T words)
  {
      return (T) Collections2.transform(words, w -> w.length() + w.toUpperCase());
  }
```

Between the angle brackets `< ... >` you have the Generic Type Parameter, then following `T` is the return type of the method and obviously it takes 1 parameter of the same type `T`.